# Upgrade (unisntall/install) Windows Service using InstallShield Setup Project

Tags: windows-services, upgrade, installshield

My question, is there a way to configure the InstallShield setup and deployment project so that when I attempt to install the service it will uninstall the previously installed version of the service.

I've created a Windows Service and an InstallShield setup and deployment project to be able to install it onto my machine. The process of installing and uninstalling the service all works fine. When I go to update the service, at the moment, I need to stop the service, uninstall the service manually, and then run the installer. What I am trying to get to is a point where I can run the installer and it will uninstall the previous version of the service before installing the current version.

I have seen this process of running the install and having the previous versions uninstalled work. Through creating a test project using a windows form application. I was able to install the application. Then I: incremented the product version, created a new product code, added a new upgrade entry in the upgrade path area, and configured that upgrade entry setting the min and max version. After doing this, I rebuilt the setup project and ran the installer and the upgrade from version A to version B was complete.

The only difference I believe from the original test project (where I saw the process work) and my Windows Service project is that my test project was a Windows Forms application versus a Windows Service. In all the research I have been doing I have seen people ask similar questions, but I have not seen any real suggestions on what actions to take. So if anyone knows if this is possible or has any suggestions that I could try to accomplish this task they would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve this issue, so it is possible. The setting I mentioned above are the correct settings needed to allow the service to update. This was just a case of human error that was causing my problems.